# Open source CMS with multi-language support

Tags: open-source, web-apps, cms

I'm looking for an open source CMS that meets these requirements:

- multi language support (including right to left languages)
- responsive design (mobile friendly)
- open and extensible for further developments (pages as well as database), ability to add my own database (or tables)
- create my own pages accessing the tables
- ability to define different access levels
- ability to handle heavy traffic in the future
- can communicate easily with other systems
- Integration with social network
- fast deployment
- strong developer community and hosting service available.

I know there are a lot of options including WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, etc. I just don't know which one is better for me. I've also heard about WCM like Sitecore. I'm not sure if they work for me or not. I have no problem with technical issues too.

Comment: I found CMSmatrix [link](http://www.cmsmatrix.org/) that compare all CMSs. I'm not sure how much I can rely on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org)

It has all the features built in:

- [multi language support](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/multilingual)
- responsive design (a lot of [themes](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_theme))
- open and extensible
- own content types
- multiple access levels
- handles heavy traffic (optimization & cache included)
- communicates easily with other systems (API)
- integration with social network ([OAuth2](https://www.drupal.org/node/2300493))
- fast deployment
- strong developer community

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend WordPress. It meets all of your requirements either through Wordpress itself or using themes & plugins. Here is a list of your recommendations and how I would go about them,

- multi-language support, use the plugin [Google Language Translator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator)
- responsive design, use a theme that's responsive (there's [quite a few](https://wordpress.org/themes/tags/responsive-layout/) out there)
- open and extensible for further developments (pages as well as a database), ability to add my own database (or tables) - you can do this by editing the posts table
- create my own pages accessing the tables - I do this all the time, simply create a function (in PHP) where it would access the table you want and return the results how you want, finally attach the function to a shortcode and you're done.
- ability to define different access levels - can be done simply using a role editor, like [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/)
- ability to handle heavy traffic in the future - you can use a cache program to help, like [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)
- can communicate easily with other systems - There are lots of integrations with WordPress and other systems, if you have something specific in mind, please leave a comment asking
- Integration with social network - Yep, there're quite a few plugins that'll do just that, here's one [Mashshare](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mashsharer/)
- fast deployment - If you're talking about the speed of which you can develop plugins, it's really simple too if you have a decent understand of PHP and take a look at a few guides on WordPress.org. If you're talking about the development of WordPress, there are constantly updates being made every day.
- strong developer community and hosting service available. - There's an awesome community over at [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) and WordPress basically runs on any hosts that support PHP & MySQL.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask in a comment:)

## [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/) ([open source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/license.txt))

> WordPress is a state-of-the-art publishing platform with a focus on aesthetics, web standards, and usability.
>
> More simply, WordPress is what you use when you want to work with your blogging software, not fight it.
>
> Self-hosted WordPress software is free, hosting service at WordPress.com is freemium.
>
> [image: WordPress Dashboard Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer @Tom. Google translation won't work for me. I need to have the same page translated by the content team and let the user select language anywhere in the site. 
How do you compare it with others? This link below says when it comes to moderation, Drupal is the most flexible one. [link](http://websitesetup.org/cms-comparison-wordpress-vs-joomla-drupal/)

Comment: @MahdiSahebnasagh If you want to translate pages yourself, then I would check out a plugin called [polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) (also check [this out](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress)) - in regard to moderation (I've never used Drupal as I've never had too), but WordPress's Comment Moderation is pretty flexible I feel but if it's not enough for you, it can be extended through plugins, here's a sample of what the [comment moderation dashboard looks like](http://www.blog2brand.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/comments-1024x735.png)

Comment: @MahdiSahebnasagh For multilingual Wordpress, check out [qTranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) or [WPML](https://wpml.org/).

Comment: Drupal is quite capable of handling multiple databases, WordPress sadly can only handle a single database.

Comment: @pacmaninbw You're incorrect on that, WordPress can handle an unlimited about of external databases, maybe you're thinking that at it's core it's only running off of one database? But I've made custom plugins for people where they fetch and send data from about 3 external databases and WordPress is quite compatible with it.

Comment: But Drupal core handles it without plugins.

Comment: @pacmaninbw ok, that may be true but what does that have to do with external databases?

Comment: In Drupal I can use the Drupal database handlers to handle access to multiple databases, that allows easier access to both databases. That way if I need to transfer a website, or say transfer a wordpress blog from one website to another I only need to specify which database I want to query. I can't do this in WordPress, but I can in Drupal. I specifically need to transfer a WordPress Blog from one site to another, the second one has more than just posts. It would be so much easier if I could just open both databases and transfer what was necessary rather than exporting and importing.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Not sure where the OP said anything about transferring content but in WP it's really not all that hard, you can just export the database and import it wherever you need it, not sure what's so challenging about that. Anyway, let's not fight over which CMS is better to use, you think Drupal is, I think WP is, both will work quite well in regard to the OP's requirements.

Comment: There are drawbacks to Drupal, using WordPress, I can keep WordPress up to date (both core and plugins) by enabling wordpress to update. In Drupal I have to update externally and any updates require testing before implementation. WordPress has a plugin for anti-virus and anti-spam, drupal doesn't..

Answer (score 3):

[Wolf CMS](https://www.wolfcms.org/) is a PHP-based opensource (GPLv3) content management system, using any of mySQL, SQlite, or PostgreSQL for the database. I've used it for years (full disclosure: as part of core "team", mostly involved in documentation), and find it a very flexible, easy-to-use system.

The "multilanguage" aspect: the backend is available in [36 different languages](https://github.com/wolfcms/wolfcms/tree/master/wolf/app/i18n), while frontend multilingual support is available via a "core" plugin (there is more than one strategy for dealing with this, depending on site setup).

As for OP's reqirements:

- [image: Yes] multi language support (including [right to left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzNQW.png) languages) | **yes, out-of-the-box**
- [image: Note] responsive design (mobile friendly) | **[layouts available](https://www.wolfcms.org/wiki/themes:start)** (See Baseline, Bootstrap, GGS, and Scherzo)
- [image: Yes] open and extensible for further developments (pages as well as database), ability to add my own database (or tables) | **yes**
- [image: Yes] create my own pages accessing the tables | **yes**
- [image: Yes] ability to define different access levels | **yes** (user management enhanced via plugins)
- [image: Yes] ability to handle heavy traffic in the future | **yes, using "Funky Cache" plugin serves site as static pages**
- [image: Note] can communicate easily with other systems | **?? not sure what is in mind here**
- [image: Note] Integration with social network | **via plugins**
- [image: Yes] fast deployment | **yes** (installed in [less than 5 minutes](https://youtu.be/66BoegrqDxw))
- [image: Yes] strong developer community |  **yes**; but [image: No] **no** hosting service available.

There are a variety of [admin themes](https://www.wolfcms.org/wiki/admin_themes:start) also available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Davïd. By 'communicate easily with other systems' I mean that to be able to use web-service or other APIs to send to and receive requests from other systems.

How do you compare it with Drupal?

Comment: But Wolf CMS seems no longer active. The [last commit](https://github.com/wolfcms/wolfcms/commits/master) is from August 2015.

Comment: @niutech It's just a lull. :) There are lots of other branches, and team members (and lead dev) have their own repos they pull from when ready. Drop into [the forum](http://j.mp/wcmsForum) (also not hyperactive at the moment!) if you're interested in roadmap things.